# The active window in windows 7 automatically changes for no obvious reason

Tags: windows-7

While I am doing anything from running a program to typing in a text field on my web browser, the active window seems to change to nothing, stealing the keyboard or if it is a full screen application, it minimizes the current window.

I have a fairly new installation of Windows 7 and it is completely updated at the moment.  I've run virus scans and adware scans and still can't seem to find what the root problem is.  Any ideas on why the active window would automatically deactivate?

Comment: Type **mouse** in the Start Menu search box, then click on **Change how your mouse works**. Are you sure you don't have the **Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse** setting enabled? Also, try disabling all programs that run at Startup via **msconfig**, then reboot and see if this still happens. If it doesn't, re-enable apps one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: If your program "locks up" for more than 5 seconds, it can loose focus.